# Initializing a log object for all classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a winforms application with lot's of classes, and in every class I need to write to a log if something goes wrong.

Today I made a logger function that I initialize in every class object for using it inside.

For example I have a main logic class that have log and one more class that's running different logic that should have a log.

Today I am using:

- Initialize log object in class contractor for working with it.
- passing log object to the contractor.

what will be the best architecture for initialize it one time and use it in every class (Not doing it static).

My logger class:

```
namespace MyLogger
{
    public class Logger : IMessageLogger
    {
        IMessageLogger _messageLogger;

        public Logger(IMessageLogger messageLogger)
        {
            _messageLogger = messageLogger;
        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            _messageLogger.Log(message);
        }
    }

    public interface IMessageLogger
    {
        void Log(string message);
    }

    public class FileLogger : IMessageLogger
    {
        string _filePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        public string filePath
        {
            get { return _filePath; }
            set { _filePath = value; }
        }

        public FileLogger(string filePath)
        {
            _filePath = filePath;
        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            string strFileName = Path.Combine(_filePath, String.Format("{0}{1}.log", _filePath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strFileName, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss]") + "  ->  " + message);
            };
        }
    }

    public class ConsoleLogger : IMessageLogger
    {
        public void Log(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use a static log class --- I believe this is a common approach. Make the class static and the log function static as well. You will then be able to reference it all over your project as long as the namespace is included.

Comment: yes, static is one way and i don't need to create object in this case but is it right way?

Comment: It would be hard for me to tell you if this is the "right" way. But it will be a clean straightforward solution to your question. In my opinion, this is the right way, but there are many other SO'ers with more experience that will probably contradict me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way is to implement it via DependencyInjection, you should read about it online.
But if you want a quick and easy solution, simply implement a Singleton pattern for your logger, like such -

```
public class Logger : IMessageLogger
{
    private IMessageLogger _messageLogger;
    private static Logger _instance;

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                // Pick one:
                _instance = new Logger(new FileLogger("SomePath"));
                _instance = new Logger(new ConsoleLogger());
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Logger(IMessageLogger messageLogger)
    {
        _messageLogger = messageLogger;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        _messageLogger.Log(message);
    }
}
```

And to write a log use this line -

```
Logger.Instance.Log("This is a log message!");
```

Comment: i like that way, i will try it Thanks.

Comment: wait if the instance != null why you creating one new? :) i got the idea but you need to work on your code ;) you just need to return it.

Comment: I meant to write it as == null.
You're right, sorry about the error, just wrote it down automatically :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides to my answer.

The first, to get the behavior you want, make the class and methods static. This creates one instance for the lifetime of your application and you can just use `FileLogger.Log` wherever you need it without having to new a new `FileLogger` up.I am not sure why you are adverse to using a static though, so you could get the same behavior with a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

The second is that you should not be writing your own logger. There are so many good, open source options available. Look at [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/), [nLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.4.0-betaV15) or even the built in [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) to save yourself the effort of re-inventing the wheel.